# Copy values to a different workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I want to update this code so it copies the values to a new workbook in csv format instead of sheet2 on same workbook. Thanks

```
Option Explicit
Dim TimeToRun
Sub chkTimer()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
TimeToRun = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "runMacro"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
Sub runMacro()
Calculate
Sheet1.Range("A1:D12").Copy
Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
chkTimer
End Sub
Sub stopMacro()
On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "runMacro", , False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is basic code to create a new workbook and transfer your range to Sheet1 in the new workbook, no copy/paste. It will save the new workbook, as an `.xlsx` file, to the same folder your macro enable workbook is located, using `Thisworkbook.Path`. Then name the new workbook "Test", change name as needed. Comments provided in the code.

Replace these two lines...

```
Sheet1.Range("A1:D12").Copy
Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

With...

```
Dim newWB As Workbook: Set newWB = Workbooks.Add 'create new workbook

    With newWB
        'You Don't need to Copy/Paste, use the equals method to get the values
        .Sheets(1).Range("A1:D12").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D12").Value
        'Save the new workbook to the same folder ThisWorkbook is located
        .SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Test" & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, this is easy and excellent. One issue though, when replaced with new code its trying to save a new Test workbook every 10 seconds instead of appending in one sheet. Also, could we create the destination workbook in .csv format? Appreciate your help.

Comment: Don't put comments as an answer, use `add a comment`. With that said, it runs every 10 seconds because your code `TimeToRun = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")` is causing it. You can change the new workbook name from `Test` to anything you want. Change the `.xlsx`. to `.cvs` and `FileFormat:=51` to `FileFormat:=6`

Comment: I understand. And I have to log the values every 10 seconds. And it has to append on the same sheet.